# socket.io client receives wrong data

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, socket.io, zeromq

i have a real time project that for some reason my socket.io client receives that data emitted from the server incorrectly. i don't necessarily receive an error when i console log it, it seems to get something just not whats expected. this is what i receive:

client console:
[image]

pretty new to this so i don't know what that log means. to explain my code, its a mixture of php with zmq to transfer data from wordpress to javascript, essentially to update a post in real time. when i log the data the socket.io server receives the data correctly from the php side of things, just seems like something is lost in translation when going from socket server to socket client.

socket.io server:

```
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');
const zmq = require('zmq'),
  zSock = zmq.socket('pull');
  zSock.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5556');


// app set up
const app = express();
const server = http.Server(app);

let port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// static files
app.use(express.static('app'));

// socket setup & pass SERVER
const io = new socketIO(server);

// on client connect
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

  console.log('client has entered...');

//when data is received from php/zmq, emit data
  zSock.on('message', (data) => {

    console.log('zmq data: ', data);
    socket.emit('test', data);

  });

});
```

socket.io client:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

  const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080/');

  class ShowTeam {

    constructor(){
      this.teamOutput = $('.team-random__output');
      this.events();

    }

    events() {
      socket.on('test', (data) => {

        console.log('connected!');

        console.dir(data);
        console.log('client data: ' + data);

      });
    }

  }

export default ShowTeam;
```

this is the correct data the socket.io server receives, and is supposed to be emitted to the client. it is supposed to be an html string with some quotes removed so it is transferred correctly via json:

```
zmq data:  {"updated_post_content":"<div class= team-container team-container--inline col col--md-2 col--lg-2 col--xl-2><img src=/card-store/wp-content/themes/card-store-theme/images/baseball/team0.jpg> <p>Brianne<p/></div><div class= team-container team-container--inline col col--md-2 col--lg-2 col--xl-2><img src=/card-store/wp-content/themes/card-store-theme/images/baseball/team1.jpg> <p>Brianne<p/></div><div class= team-container team-container--inline col col--md-2 col--lg-2 col--xl-2><img src=/card-store/wp-content/themes/card-store-theme/images/baseball/team2.jpg> <p>Brianne<p/></div><div class= team-container team-container--inline col col--md-2 col--lg-2 col--xl-2><img src=/card-store/wp-content/themes/card-store-theme/images/baseball/team3.jpg> <p>Brianne<p/></div><div class= team-container team-container--inline col col--md-2 col--lg-2 col--xl-2><img src=/card-store/wp-content/themes/card-store-theme/images/baseball/team4.jpg> <p>Brianne<p/></div>"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The object received from the zmq socket is a buffer, a serialization of the data. To get the object from it, you must do `const msg = JSON.parse(data.toString());`.